# phpunit: when is useful an expects any() ?, why exists?

Tags: phpunit

Sometimes I see some people writing

```
->expects($this->any())
```

Seems to me completely redundant. For me means "I don't care about this expectation", am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a good example for chained calls (taken [from here](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/a-great-way-to-mock-chained-calls-in-phpunit))

```
$this->someService
     ->getSomething()
     ->getSomethingElse()
     ->doMore($x)
     ->proceed()
     ->toGetTheFinalCall($y);
```

If you want to mock it in traditional way you would end up in creating separate mocks for every single call! Which will grow easily to a half of screen of of code just to mock one line! But wait there is a way!

```
$value = 'some mocked value';    

$mock = $this->getMock('ServiceClass', array('getSomething',
        'getSomethingElse','doMore','proceed','toGetTheFinalCall' ), array(), '', false);

$mock->expects($this->any())->method('toGetTheFinalCall')
        ->will($this->returnValue($value));

$mock->expects($this->any())->method($this->anything())
        ->will($this->returnValue($mock));
```

This way every consecutive call to the mock returns itself so it can be chained as many times as you want. You wont check if methods are called in the desired order but that is not really a problem. Ultimately what you want is to test the code that does something with the results of the call.

Comment: aaaah, good, that is good. But in that case my guess is that you can just remove the ```->expects($this->any())```. They just look weird

Comment: You are right. But it may be there for documentation purposes: we explicitly say "can be called as many times as necessary". Explicit is better than implicit, right? :) But of course its the matter of taste.

Comment: or also, when that method is within loop